# Can a telephone call be intercepted with React Native

Tags: react-native, telecom

Thanks for reading my post.

I work in a company that works with telecom. We have an app made with React Native. The app can do all sorts of stuff like call transfer, Do-not-disturb etc.

However, I would like the app to do something specific when the phone rings.

I know it can be done in native (java, swift) - but can it be done in react native?

Comment: yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874219/react-native-trigger-user-phone-call-incoming-on-action-in-app

Answer (score 0):

If it can be done in java/swift, it can be done in react native.

You can easily code the program in java and then call it from react native, such as all react native packages with native code: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Another alternative is to find someone that has already done that.